# POST request endpoint using Java/Spring-boot OWL

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a post request endpoint to send some form values to my database. When I test the request with postman, I get a 400 bad request error and this message in my console

JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type abcd.Model.Quote from Array value (token JsonToken.START_ARRAY);

this is my controller:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping("/createQuote")
    public boolean newQuote(@RequestBody Quote newQuote) {
    return quoteDB.saveQuote(newQuote);
};
```

my model:

```
public class Quote {
public int id;
public String type_building;
public int numElevator;
public String typeService;
public double total;
public double totalElevatorPrice;

public Quote(
        int _id,
        String _type_building,
        int _numElevator,
        String _typeService,
        double _total,
        double _totalElevatorPrice
){
    this.id = _id;
    this.type_building = _type_building;
    this.numElevator = _numElevator;
    this.typeService = _typeService;
    this.total = _total;
    this.totalElevatorPrice = _totalElevatorPrice;

}
public String getType_building() { return type_building; }
public void setType_building(String type_building) { this.type_building = type_building; }

public int getNumElevator() { return numElevator; }
public void setNumElevator(int numElevator) { this.numElevator = numElevator; }

public String getTypeService() { return typeService; }
public void setTypeService(String typeService) { this.typeService = typeService; }

public double getTotal() { return total; }
public void setTotal(int total) { this.total = total; }

public double getTotalElevatorPrice() { return totalElevatorPrice; }
public void setTotalElevatorPrice(int totalElevatorPrice) { this.totalElevatorPrice = totalElevatorPrice; }
```

Comment: Some questions for you to think about: When do you expect `taxPayers.dupID(i) == taxPayers.dupID(i)` to be false? If you want to compare two different objects, don't you need two different indices? Shouldn't you gather all the information *before* printing the report? Isn't `((i + x) - (i))` just `x`?

Comment: How would I go about this? I expect taxPayers.dupID(i) == taxPayers.dupID(i) with every other ID except the identical ones and thank you for the x thing, over-complicating something for no reason.

Comment: Why do you expect `i` to have two *different* values is `taxPayers.dupID(i) == taxPayers.dupID(i)`? (Hint: you can have a loop within a loop.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in opt_D() method you should find the duplicate dupIDs and insert them into a list.
Then in order to give the output you should traverse the duplicate list and find corresponding vales from taxPayers.

```
 // define a list for duplicate ids. 


for (size_t i = 0; i < taxPayers.taxPayers.size(); ++i)
    {
     for (size_t j = i+1; j < taxPayers.taxPayers.size(); ++j)
          {
            if (taxPayers.dupID(i) == taxPayers.dupID(j))
            {

             // push taxPayers.dupID(i) to the duplicate id list


           }
        }
    }


// print duplicate list size as output
// traverse the duplicate id list and find taxPayers having the same dupID from taxPayers list and print their info.
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. It would find each element as a duplicate. You would need to start the inner loop with j=i+1.

Comment: @ArminMontigny, you are right. I updated the code. Thanks for your care.